# Field level Validation Rule => "OnSave"?

Tags: templates, validation

I need an 8 characters length enforcing validator. I created a MaxLength=8 and combined it with a MinLength=8 validation rule.

Then I enter "1234567890123' and it's saving, no question asked!

It does work if I click the "REVIEW" tab then "Validation". At the very bottom of a long list of schema warnings for each and every field. Our users won't do that.

I've been researching quite a bit already. One talk about "Quick Action Bar" that I don't see anywhere, and so on. I just need a simple, text field validation like exist in any html form. You enter data wrong, it displays a message and you can't save. Period. How do you do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

you missed to add Parameters on your validator

[image]

Parameters are applied using a QueryString-like list like this:

[parameter]=[value]&[parameter]=[value]

The “Result” paremeter determines the default result value of a validation.

Possible values are:

**Valid** = Green, everything is fine

**Suggestion** = Bright Orange, hmm, take a look at this

**Warning** = Orange, you should do something about this

**Error** = Red, this is an error you know

**CriticalError**  = Red, user is warned before saving

**FatalError** = Red, user cannot save item before validator is cleared

More informations you can find [here](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-sitecore-field-validators/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I think I was using CriticalError, and/or possibly didn't Save after adding the "Result" parameter.

Also it takes a bit of trial and error to choose the right of the 4 "Quick Action Bar", "Validate Button", "Validator bar", and "Workflow" that'll be responsive to the "Save" button. 

I found out that it was #3, "Validator bar" without really knowing how/why but that's OK!

One thing I'm still not able to get, is the **Text=** parameter like the Sample SSN has:

Pattern=^[0-9]{8}$**&Text=**Field "{0}" needs to be an 8 digit value. Example: 01065743&Result=FatalError

Answer (score 3):

As well as using a rules engine based validator, there are also validation fields on the Field template that you can use:

[image: Field template validation fields]

The `Validation` field takes a regex and the `ValidationText` field can be used for the warning text. Using the following regex:

```
/^.{8,}$/
```

That makes sure that the content has a minimum length of 8 characters. Now when the content editor tries to save an item that fails that validation, the message will be shown and the user cannot save the item:

[image: Validation failed]

This can be a simpler setup than rules based validation, although it is limited to what you can do with a single regex statement.

Comment: Thanks a plenty! I had missed this simpler way completely, online material is somewhat more focused on the other, more complex but reusable way. I've removed the '/' and made it digit only like so:
^[0-9]{8}$